# OSX Mac SnowLeopard Bootcamp Windows7 ATI Radeon 6750 black screen upon startup after installing Mountain Lion

Tags: windows-7, macos, boot-camp, ati-mobility-radeon

I updated my MacBookPro to Mountain Lion from Snow Leopard a while ago and hadn't tested going into Bootcamp for quite some time. I recently did and found the much talked about 'black screen of death' appearing after the normal 'Starting Windows...' graphic.

After much searching I could only find people talking about this happening immediately after installing bootcamp or in the middle of installing bootcamp and Windows7 but not when you have had a working installation of Windows7 via Bootcamp which now is broken due to Snow Leopard.

I can still get into Win7 via Safe Mode and did run the ATI Catalyst to update my AMD Radeon drivers but to no avail. It still does not work...

Any suggestions?

Thanks
- J

Comment: How long did you let it sit a the black screen for? And instead of Safe Mode, did you (since you seem to suspect video drivers) try the "Enable low-resolution video (640×480)" mode?

Comment: For a while ... nothing was happening. I will try the low-res video mode. I noticed that even after safe mode (when doing what some people suggested: which is to remove a .sys file from my ATI folder) it does boot up but obv but w/o graphics...